# Call db.close() on Button_Click (QT/C++)

Tags: c++, database, button, qt6

how can i close a database connction from Button_onClick funktion?

```
    Artikelverwaltung::Artikelverwaltung(QWidget *parent) :
        QDialog(parent),
        ui(new Ui::Artikelverwaltung)
    {
      ...
    
        QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    ...
    }
    
    void Artikelverwaltung::on_pushButton_clicked()
    {
        db.close(); // <---- This is not working of cause. how can i do this?
}
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because db is a local variable in `Artikelverwaltung::Artikelverwaltung` you need to make it a class attribute.

```
class Artikelverwaltung
{
  private:
    QSqlDatabase m_db;
};




Artikelverwaltung::Artikelverwaltung(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Artikelverwaltung)
{
  ...

    m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
...
}

void Artikelverwaltung::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    m_db.close();
}
```